# SqlClientPermission in a sandbox web part

Tags: sharepoint, exception, permissions, trust

I'm trying a long time to get a working SQL connection in my web part. I read a lot of msdn stuff and tried many things, but I can't get it working... Every time I try to open a SQL connection, my web part throw an exception: `Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission`.

I tried custom.configs which set the .net trust higher, edit the manifest, set the permissions with the PermissionSet-Class and also tried FullTrust, but nothing worked. How do I set the permission correctly? 
Btw, the web part is a sandbox solution.

It would be awesome if someone could  give me a detailed view, how to set the permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of operation, You need to develop a full trust proxy([SPProxyOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.usercode.spproxyoperation.aspx)) to be used by your Sandbox Solutions.

The sandbox solutions has Code Access Security and Permission restrictions. For details you can visit:
http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2011/10/07/sharepoint-sandbox-reallly-new-feature/

Comment: I have never tried it with SPProxyOperation. I will try it tomorrow and give you feedback if its work.

Comment: Okay, it doesn’t work :(. I also tested it with a standard web part. Here the connection works without any problems. I will let you know, if there is something new.